# Two thread call join in java

Tags: java

Example i have 2 thread: t1 and t2 and my code is

```
t1.start();
t2.start();

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

I already known the concept of join method. But in this case i don't know the mechanism of join method. Which thread will wait for other complete ?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is fully answered by the Javadoc.

Comment: It's also hard to understand how you can claim to 'know the concept' of `join()` when you clearly don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thread(main, implicit) which starts `t1` and `t2` waits for `t1` and `t2` to complete, respectively.

Comment: In particular, it first waits for t1 to complete and then t2 to complete.

Comment: In other words, they (t1 & t2) don't run in parallel.

Comment: @zgulser No! t1 & t2 run in parallel of course! But the main thread waits them in a given order (it waits the end of t1 and then those of t2 whatever the order they really terminate by).

Comment: Hey! Your comment just occured to me this; if there's a chance of t2 to finish her job before t1, then in this case, t2 object might get deleted after executing it's own run method but before t1 finishes. If so, calling join on t2 could make the app crash. What do u think?

Comment: @zgulser An object, including a thread, cannot be 'deleted', by which I assume you mean garbage-collected, while there is a reachable reference to it, such as `t2`.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I meant GCing of course :).  I somehow thought that t2 would get removed once the thread executes it's run method which apparently was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The `join()` method waits for a thread to die. In other words, it causes currently running threads to stop executing until the thread it joins completes its task.

The main thread will wait for all child threads to finish. The main thread will start `t1` and joins `t2` with it. Once thread `t2` completes, its task `t1` will be executing again.

Comment: Nothing right about this answer beyond the first sentence. `join()` blocks the *current* thread until the target thread exits, not all currenty running threads. The main thread will not wait for all child threads to finish. It does not join `t2` with `t1`. `t1` will not be executing again after `t1.join()`. You don't appear to understand the first thing about it.